# JavaFx: SplitPane dynamic scrollBar

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scrollpane, splitpane

I have a problem with the `SplitPane` inside a `ScrollPane`.
I need an extendable scrollPane similar to the `TableView` so when I have too many items I have scrollbar, when all of my items are visible then hide the scrollbar.

ScrollPane has a switch : `fitToHeight` but both true/false doesn't do the job I need. 
I will upload two screenshots to show what I mean. 
If it is set to `true` then I simply don't have the scroll which is not a solution because I may have too much data to fit in one window so I need the scroll.
If it is set to `false` then I always have scrollbar even if there is no data to show at the bottom of the view.

I would like to be the scrollbar dynamic, so when I drag the last divider and there is no space to fit the last item, the scrollbar should appear, when there is space for every item in the `SplitPane` then it should not be displayed.

Any idea how can it be achieved?

The relevant code:

Fxml:

```
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<ScrollPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fitToWidth="true"
            fx:controller="test.Controller">
    <SplitPane fx:id="splitPane" orientation="VERTICAL">
        <VBox spacing="5" minHeight="20">
            <Label text="*Title*" VBox.vgrow="NEVER"/>
            <TextArea VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS"/>
        </VBox>
        <VBox minHeight="20" spacing="5">
            <Label text="*Title*" VBox.vgrow="NEVER"/>
            <TableView VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                <columns>
                    <TableColumn/>
                </columns>
            </TableView>
        </VBox>
        <VBox minHeight="20" spacing="5">
            <Label text="*Title*" VBox.vgrow="NEVER"/>
            <TableView VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                <columns>
                    <TableColumn/>
                </columns>
            </TableView>
        </VBox>
        <VBox minHeight="20" spacing="5">
            <Label text="*Title*" VBox.vgrow="NEVER"/>
            <TextArea VBox.vgrow="NEVER"/>
        </VBox>
        <padding>
            <Insets topRightBottomLeft="5"/>
        </padding>
    </SplitPane>
</ScrollPane>
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private SplitPane splitPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        splitPane.setDividerPositions(0d,.33d, .66d,1d);
    }

}
```

Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("View.fxml"));
        ScrollPane pane = loader.load();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 800, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Here I have the scrollbar even if there is no need to scroll, every item is visible**

[image: Fit off]

**Here I don't have the scrollbar**

[image: Fit on]

Comment: on face value, it looks like a misconception of "empty space": the pref/height of the splitpane is still the same - doesn't matter if the sum of the really visible is less. So the scrollPane has no reason to adjust its scrollbar. To see that: keep only the first two and see how the scrollbar appears/disappears on resizing the window (if its fitToHeight is false). Don't know how to solve (could even be a bug in any of the layouts), my direction would be to find a way to make the splitpane recalc its pref.

Comment: @kleopatra true, it is not "empty", it is the last item in my case the `VBox` I am trying to recalc the scrollPane's or splitPane's height, but something fails every time. I keep trying, I asked it if someone had some similar problem, or knows the solution to help me :)

Comment: how are you trying to calculate the height and how is it failing?

Comment: What if you set the `minHeight` property of the `SplitPane` to `Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`?

Comment: @Slaw it doesn't work. Almost same as before, there is the scrollbar but if I try to drag the last divider it hides simply the last item in the splitpane and doesn't extend the pane to scroll down.

Comment: @b3tuning I tried to bruteforce it, so adding a listener to the last item's height and recalculate the height of the splitpane when the last item's height changes. It worked in a way but it caused other glitches.